# Why my custom checkbox in listview can't be checked

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to set the checked state of my checkbox in listview, here's the code:

```
mShalatAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.pengaturan_list_item, R.id.label_shalat, waktuShalat);

mListShalat = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.pengaturan_checkbox);
mListShalat.setAdapter(mShalatAdapter);

CheckBox cb;
TextView txv;
for (int i = 0; i < mListShalat.getCount(); i++) {
    View vListSortOrder = mListShalat.getAdapter().getView(i, null, null);
    txv = (TextView) vListSortOrder.findViewById(R.id.label_shalat);
    cb = (CheckBox) vListSortOrder.findViewById(R.id.status_shalat);

    String labelShalat = txv.getText().toString();
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), labelShalat, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if (cb.isChecked() == false) {
        cb.setChecked(true);
    }
}
```

And this is my `pengaturan_list_item.xml` layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label_shalat"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Label Ibadah"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/status_shalat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:button="@drawable/ibadah_checkbox_list"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I got the value for TextView and CheckBox but I don't know why the CheckBox not showing the true state in device. Please help, thanks in advance.

my ibadah_checkbox_list.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_checked="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_ibadah_checked" />
    <item android:state_checked="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_ibadah_unchecked" />
</selector>
```

Comment: please post the idadah_checkbox_list drawable xml (I'm assuming it's an xml)

Comment: @GilMoshayof ok, please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be worth altering the way your adapter works.

Instead of creating a stardard ArrayAdapter, try inheriting from it instead, then inflating views from the list_item.xml inside the getView() method.

Once there, you can extract the checkbox from the view like you're doing in the loop & set its value according to what you need. This is the standard way of doing things like this.

My guess for why what you're doing is not working is that the ArrayAdapter is creating the views when it needs to display them, rather than in this loop you're using, so while it generates and gives you the views while you're requesting them, these views won't necessarily be the ones that are displayed.

Here's how I would do it:

```
public class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
    {
        public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<String> objects)
        {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View v = convertView;

            if(v == null)
            {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.pengaturan_list_item, null);
            }

            TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.label_shalat);
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.status_shalat);

            tv.setText(getItem(position));

            if (!cb.isChecked())
                cb.setChecked(true);

            return v;
        }
    }
```

Then, set your adapter like this (`objectList` is your list of Strings for the labels):

```
mShalatAdapter = new MyArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.pengaturan_list_item, objectList);
mListShalat = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.pengaturan_checkbox);
mListShalat.setAdapter(mShalatAdapter);
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks Gil, this is the last thing I want do

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that in your layout. Your `TextView` has a `layout_width` of `match_parent`, and in that it covers the `CheckBox` and fills the whole width layout. So you need to divide the layout properly.

Try the layout below and tell me the effect.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:paddingTop="5dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label_shalat"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Label Ibadah"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/status_shalat"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:button="@drawable/ibadah_checkbox_list"
        android:visibility="visible" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` in your ListView.Hope it works....